# Add input to form using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's possible to add inputs that are created dynamically by the user to a form?

Let's say I have this when the page loads:

```
<form id="my-form" xl-form>
... // here the inputs
</form>
```

And after that, I create an input (after the page loads)

```
<input type="input" class="integr_elements" placeholder="name" id="name">
```

How can I add it inside the form that has "my-form" as id?
I need to add it inside because i want to use a GitHub plugin that will affect only the inputs that are inside the 
form.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

PS: Before posting this, searched on the forum but found 2013 post and seems there are some deprecated ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#my-form').append('<input type="input" class="integr_elements" placeholder="name" id="name">');
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) for a pure javascript solution (no jQuery).

```js
const el = document.createElement("input");
el.className = "integr_elements";
el.placeholder = "name";
el.id = "name";

const form = document.getElementById("my-form");
form.appendChild(el);
```

```html
<form id="my-form" xl-form></form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sam. Something like this? document.my-form.appendChild(name); ?

Comment: Sorry about that, was adding an example. I've included a snippet that demonstrates this!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Simply attaching or appending html content onto the form field and so on, you can change the values, names, types or even input types!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myForm").append("<input name='entry1' type='text'></input>");
  $("#myForm").append("<input name='entry2' type='password'></input>");
  $("#myForm").append("<input name='entry3' type='text'></input>");
})
```

```css
input {
display:block;
margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  
</form>
```